# What is a good way to install an interactive filter in python plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, dropdown

I would like to install a dropdown filter in python plotly - without using dash.

The solution I came up with works in case that xaxis/yaxis ranges do not change, e.g. a heatmap. In case the ranges change, it does not work well anymore.

Example: A barchart with country information. Works well for Italy and Canada. If I switch to Germany with higher population numbers than the initial country Italy, the yaxis range does not increase. How could this be fixed? Or is there a more efficient way in general?

Thanks a lot for helpful suggestions!

Example:

```
# Data
df = px.data.gapminder()
df = df[['country','year', 'pop']]
df.head(3)
```

```
# Create Barchart
def generate_barchart(ins):
    fig = px.bar(df[df['country']==ins], x='year', y='pop')
    return fig

# Dropdown: Content
uplist1 = ['Italy', 'Canada', 'Germany']
uplist2 = [generate_barchart(ins) for ins in uplist1]

# Dropdown: Implementation
upfilter = [{'method': 'animate', 'label': i1, 'args': [i2]} for i1, i2  in zip(uplist1, uplist2)]
updatemenus = [{'buttons': upfilter}]

# Initial barchart
fig = go.Figure(uplist2[0])

# Add dropdown
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus)

# Result
fig
```

Works well for Italy and Canada:
[image]

Outside range:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see two options how to make the Y axis right (besides manually resetting it). Both set [`range`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis-range) for Y axis.

1. This alreay almost it, except the animation is a bit off (bars may go
   beyond or out of the viewport).

   ```py
   def generate_barchart(ins):
       plot_df = df[df['country'] == ins]
       fig = px.bar(plot_df, x='year', y='pop')
       fig.update_yaxes(range=[plot_df['pop'].min(), plot_df['pop'].max()])
       return fig
   ```

   To fix it you can disable animation effect by making buttons this way.

   ```py
   upfilter = [
       {
           'method': 'animate', 
           'label': i1, 
           'args': [
               i2, 
               {
                   'frame': {'duration': 0, 'redraw': False},
                   'mode': 'immediate',
                   'transition': {'duration': 0},
               },
           ]
       } 
       for i1, i2 in zip(uplist1, uplist2)
   ]
   ```
2. Alternatively you can define the range across countries.

   ```py
   def generate_barchart(ins):
       fig = px.bar(df[df['country'] == ins], x='year', y='pop')
       fig.update_yaxes(range=[
           df[df['country'].isin(uplist1)]['pop'].min(), 
           df[df['country'].isin(uplist1)]['pop'].max(),
       ])
       return fig
   ```